# java web start fails to locate java runtime

Tags: java-web-start

Hi I am trying to run javaws but it prompts:
To open this Web Start application you need to download the Java Runtime Environment.

I am sure JRE is installed, maybe javaws does not find it, how do I fix that?

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ johnmactavish$ java --version
java 13.0.2 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ johnmactavish$ javaws
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ johnmactavish$
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I still haven't.

Comment: What javaws is it running, the one with JRE 13?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java Web Start (`javaws`) was deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11.

As you are using java 13, you can either downgrade from 13 to 8, or look for alternatives.

Perhaps an alternative such as https://openwebstart.com/ can help you out with that.

P.S: In case you're using tools to manage version such as `sdkman` or such, there might be the case where it's also not available in SDKs @ version 8 provided by sdkman.